# Error:(10) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute

Tags: android

hi i have got a problem when i was making a navigation drawer.
it show me two :

> "Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute"

one of them is about my main layout and another is about my

> E:\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\main.xml

and in the down of this two error that show me this:

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt" error too.

and in the preview that say me i have two render error with these subjects

> "compilation errors" 
>   and 
>   "Missing classes"

and this is my Main Activity:

```
     package com.example.mehrad.myapplication;

     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.SharedPreferences;
     import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
     import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
         private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
         private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
         private NavigationView navigationView;
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
             new MyShared(this);
             new Names("first one");
             new Names("second one");
             RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec);
             LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new           
        LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
             recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
             MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this);
             recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
             drawerLayout =(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dl);
             navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nv);
         }
     }
```

and this is my main layout:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/dl"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <include layout="@layout/activity_main"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
            android:layout_gravity="right"    
            android:id="@+id/nv"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is my Activity main:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.example.mehrad.myapplication.MainActivity">

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/rec"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:clipToPadding="false" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my app file:

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
         compileSdkVersion 25
         buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
         defaultConfig {
             applicationId "com.example.mehrad.myapplication"
             minSdkVersion 15
             targetSdkVersion 25
             versionCode 1
             versionName "1.0"
             testInstrumentationRunner      
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         }
         buildTypes {
             release {
                 minifyEnabled false
                 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),           
     'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-     
core:2.2.2',                   {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

this is my header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_height="220dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item android:id="@+id/favorite" android:title="list"/>
         <item android:id="@+id/about" android:title="about us"/>
         <item android:id="@+id/exit" android:title="exit"/>
     </menu>
```

help me please

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this block in your `main.xml` layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/dl"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

You have the attribute `xmlns:app` twice (see the bottom line). Remove this duplicate attribute and your app should build fine, i.e.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/dl"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: thanks alot but now that give me another with this subject "Error:(10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in package 'com.example.mehrad.myapplication' "

Comment: and this "Error:(10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package 'com.example.mehrad.myapplication'"

Comment: Do you have files called `res/layout/header.xml` and `res/menu/menu.xml`?

Answer (score 25):

In my case, it happened because I specified height and width for the `layout` tag (used for data binding). These attributes should be specified only for the child which actually holds the items.

Answer (score 9):

Remove the below lines from **layout** tag

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```